# how to omit columns having null value in select query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select

```
Select Header1,Header2,Header3,ExtraHeader from tbl_likeinfo where HotelID=2
```

Here Header3 and ExtraHeader may have null values.In that case I don't need only that null value in my query result but that row containing other column values should be given.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want the columns in your result, or do you mean not the rows containing null values in those columns?

Comment: if between 5 columns 2 columns are null,it should show values for 3 columns only for that row

Comment: Then you just have your WHERE specify that by saying:  Header1 is not null AND Header2 is not null AND ...  This isn't ideal because you constantly need to update the queries as you add columns, where in this case I feel a better solution would be what I suggested in my answer.

Comment: yes but one of my table is having 10headers,so for that also i need to do 'and,and,..'?

Comment: Yes.  This will only give you records where all the headers have a value.  If one header in the row doesn't, then you will not receive any data for that row.  Based on your comment above, it sounds like you want the data that isn't null even for the records that do have null data in other fields/columns.

Comment: I have used AND for each but it still shows me that columns which are having no value in my result set

Comment: If you run:  SELECT Header1, Header2, Header3, ExtraHeader FROM table_likeinfo WHERE HotelID=2 AND Header1 is not null AND Header2 is not null AND Header3 is not null AND ExtraHeader is not null;    You should not receive any record that has a null for any one of those values.  Whether that is what you want or not is up to you.  I originally read your question as you still wanted the values that weren't null and for no column to exist where the header value was null.  This isn't possible with how your current schema is setup.  My answer below explains why and a possible solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3980/discussion-between-rc-and-heena)

Comment: onvert psv to csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't dynamically change the columns selected in the result set based on the data the query is selecting.  If you don't want to handle nulls, you could use a CASE statement on the header values to change them to a value of your choosing that represents you could treat the same way, but I wouldn't recommend that approach.

You may want to change your approach.  It appears you have your table layout using columns to represent each unique header.  If you changed your layout so the table was:

```
hotel_id     NUMBER
header_name  VARCHAR2(50)
header_value VARCHAR2(100)
```

Then when you're inserting the headers, do one insert per header received at that time.  Then change your select to:

```
SELECT header_name, header_value FROM headers WHERE hotel_id = 2;
```

If you happen to be storing header values that were null and when you pull them out, you want to eliminate those, then:

```
SELECT header_name, header_value 
FROM headers 
WHERE hotel_id = 2 AND header_value is not null;
```

If order is important to you, then add a column to the table to store the order as you insert them.  This layout also allows you to store any amount of header information without having to change the layout of the table in the future.

Hope this helps.

Comment: here header1,header2,.. itself having values

Answer (score 0):

```
AND Header3 IS NOT NULL AND ExtraHeader IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: In one of my table I am having 10 headers and 1 extraheader, In that case I need to do 'and, and, for 10 times?

Comment: I'm no SQL expert but AFAIK, yes.

Comment: @Heena, You can shorten it by doing `and coalesce(col1,col2,col3,...,col10) IS NULL`. But that might run slower because it will prevent MySQL from using an index and will prevent boolean short circuiting.